# How to prove that E is nowhere dense in X if and only if every non-empty open subset of X contains a non-empty open set disjoint form E?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Following what is written at the second chapter of "Elementos de Topología General" by Fidel Casarrubias Segura and Ángel Tamariz Mascarúa.

> The following statements are equivalent:

1. $E\subseteq X$ is nowhere dense;
2. $X\setminus\overline{E}$ is dense in $X$;
3. for any open and non empty set $A$ there exist a non empty open set $U$ such that $U\subseteq A$ and $U\cap E=\varnothing$.

To prove it I proceeded in the following way: if $E$ is nowhere dense set so by definition $\mathscr{int}(\mathscr{cl}(E))=\varnothing$ and so the set $F=\mathscr{cl}(E)$ is co-dense and by previous theorem we can say that $X=\mathscr{cl}(X\setminus F)=\mathscr{cl}(X\setminus\mathscr{cl}(E))$, and by another theorem we know that for any non empty open set $A$ it result that $A\cap X\setminus \mathscr{cl}(E)\neq\varnothing$ and so $U=A\setminus\mathscr{cl}(E)\neq\varnothing$ is an open (non empty) set such that is contained in $A$ and $U\cap E=\varnothing$, since $U\cap E=A\setminus\mathscr{cl}(E)\cap E\subseteq A\setminus E\cap E=\varnothing$, so we proved that $1\Rightarrow2\Rightarrow3$.

Unfortunately I can't prove $3\Rightarrow1$: so could someone help me, please?

Comment: How do you define “nowhere dense”?

Comment: A set is nowhere dense iff $\mathscr{int}(\mathscr{cl}(E))=\varnothing$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 3) the phrase ' there exist an open set $U$' should be changed to ' there exist a non-empty open set $U$'. [Otherwise the result is false since we can always take $U$ to be the empty set].

Suppose 3) holds and $E$ is not nowhere dense. Then the interior of $\overline {E}$ is a non-empty open set $A$. [$\overline {E}$ is the closure of $E$].  By 3) there exist a non-empty open set $U$ such that $U \subseteq A$ and $U \cap E =\emptyset$. If $x$ is any point of $U$ then $x \in A \subseteq \overline {E}$. But $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$ which does not intersect $E$. This is a  contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

For (3) to (1). Let $A:=\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(E))$. If $A$ is non-empty, assumption $3$ gives us non-empty open $U$ such that $U \subseteq A$ and $U \cap E = \emptyset$. But take $p \in U$ then $p \in A= \operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(E)) \subseteq \operatorname{cl}(E)$ so every open neighbourhood of $p$ intersects $E$. But $U$ (which is by definition an open neighbourhood of $p$) is disjoint from $U$, contradiction!

So $\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(E)) = \emptyset$, given 3, so $E$ is nowhere dense.